# How do I copy a layer or object from an AutoCAD file to another file using the pyautocad library?

Tags: python, winapi, automation, autocad

I have this code, I want to pull objects into a separate file

Code:

```
`import time
import os
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
from pyautocad.utils import unformat_mtext, timing
from progress.bar import IncrementalBar

def main():
    acad = Autocad()

    print("Need layer")
    need_layer = input()
    need_objs = []

    directory = 'to_convert'

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        document = acad.Application.Documents.Open(os.getcwd() + "/" + directory + "/" + filename)
        print("file " + filename + " opened")
        time.sleep(2)
        objs_len = acad.doc.ActiveLayout.Block.Count
        bar = IncrementalBar(' progress', max=objs_len)
        for i in range(objs_len):
            obj = next(acad.iter_objects_fast())
            bar.next()
            #print(dir(obj))
            #print(obj.Layer)
            if obj.EntityName == "AcDbPolyline" and need_layer.lower() in str(obj.Layer).lower():
                obj.Linetype = "ByLayer"
                need_objs.append(obj.Copy())
        bar.finish()

        time.sleep(1)
        doc = acad.Application.Documents.Add()
        time.sleep(1)

       
        #need_objs to doc COPY?????????    


        doc.SaveAs(os.getcwd() + "/result/" + str(filename.split('.')[:-1][0]) + "_formatted.dwg")
        time.sleep(2)
        doc.Close(False)
        time.sleep(2)
        document.Close(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with timing():
        main()
```

`
I tried this method:

`doc.CopyObjects(com_obj)`

But whatever I send to it ends up in two ways - either nothing happens and the final file does not change in any way, or an error comes out that the array sent is invalid. Please help me, I have already spent 10 hours looking for the right approach.

The work is done specifically with DWG files, variants with DXF are not suitable.